# getting hidden elements

Tags: jquery

Say I have the following unordered list

```
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item" style="display: none;">first item</li>
  <li class="item">second item</li>
  <li class="item">third item</li>
  <li class="item">forth item</li>
</ul>
```

how can I carry out a task only if all the items in the container are hidden?

regards...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector to select the visible elements only. You can use the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property to check if there is zero or more. If it equals to zero, then all elements are hidden.

```
if ($('.container .item:visible').length == 0) {
    // All is hidden.
}
```